# Shortest code to add items in List if it does not exists

Tags: c#

I have a list of objects and I am running the code below to add an object if it does not already exists in the list,

```
List<ModifiedProperty> modifiedProperties = new List<ModifiedProperty>();   
var modifiedProperty = modifiedProperties
                                    .FirstOrDefault(e => e.PropertyName == "PropertyName");
if (modifiedProperty == null) 
{
    modifiedProperty = new ModifiedProperty() { PropertyName = "PropertyName" };
    modifiedProperties.Add(modifiedProperty);
}
modifiedProperty.OldValue = "Test";
```

Can anyone provide a suggestion to add items in a shortest way possible?

Comment: There's not much more you can do, I don't think (largely because of that last line `modifiedProperty.OldValue = "Test";`)

Comment: This question should be in [Code Review Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: if you want a collection where each item is distinct, why would you not use a HashSet?

Comment: @Aidan props are not distinct i could use dictionary, but my scenario is it may add duplicate because at adds frm multiple places, my only concern is to short the code thanks

Comment: Are you using this code more than once or twice? If so, what's wrong with writing your own utility function?

Comment: What you have is not bad.  Shortest code is over rated.

Comment: @Aidan For one HashSet does not preserve order.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can simplify the code a little bit and make it more readable.

<s>1- Using "Contains" method of a list</s>

```
var modifiedProperties = new List<ModifiedProperty>();   
var modifiedProperty = new ModifiedProperty() { PropertyName = "PropertyName" };

if (!modifiedProperties.Contains(modifiedProperty)) 
{
    modifiedProperties.Add(modifiedProperty);
    modifiedProperty.OldValue = "Test";
}
```

2- Using Exists

```
var modifiedProperties = new List<ModifiedProperty>();   
var modifiedProperty = new ModifiedProperty() { PropertyName = "PropertyName" };

if (!modifiedProperties.Exists(x => x.PropertyName == modifiedProperty.PropertyName)) 
{
    modifiedProperties.Add(modifiedProperty);
    modifiedProperty.OldValue = "Test";
}
```

3- Using Except and Concat //if you have 2 lists

```
var modifiedProperties = new ModifiedProperty() { PropertyName = "PropertyName" };

var allProperties = //some old props

var result = modifiedProperties.Concat(allProperties.Except(modifiedProperties));
//this way you will get a new list of all the properties
//this will preserve the order of the list as well

//simple version of above (won't maintain order)
allProperties.Except(modifiedProperties).Concat(modifiedProperties);
```

4- Use Union, here is the ref https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731(v=vs.110).aspx

```
var newProps = allProps.Union(modifiedProps);
```

1 is wrong.  Do I have to spell it out?  Testing of 1 is severely incomplete.

```
var modifiedProperties = new List<ModifiedProperty>();
var modifiedProperty = new ModifiedProperty() { PropertyName = "PropertyName" };

Debug.WriteLine("Contains " + modifiedProperties.Contains(modifiedProperty));

if (!modifiedProperties.Contains(modifiedProperty))
{
    modifiedProperties.Add(modifiedProperty);

    modifiedProperty.OldValue = "Test";
}

Debug.WriteLine("Contains " + modifiedProperties.Contains(modifiedProperty));

modifiedProperty = new ModifiedProperty() { PropertyName = "PropertyName" };
Debug.WriteLine("Contains " + modifiedProperties.Contains(modifiedProperty));
```

Comment: why not @Paparazzi ?

Comment: Create a class for yourself and test

Comment: It is not working.  Learn to properly test.   Create another   modifiedProperties and see if it is found.

Comment: @Paparazzi it is working. I don't know what you saw or if you were unable to read the code or see the link. Here is the image of output with the code. here is the link to the image https://imgur.com/a/4T2nF

Comment: You have NOT properly tested.  I already told you what to test for.

Comment: Please create a test on dotnetfiddle and I will see it cuz I can't understand what do you mean it won't work. What type of use case your are saying it won't work in. As finding a property in a list of properties it is working fine (as seen in the image). Could you please create a fiddle for me. TY

Comment: You test one modifiedProperties.  I was very clear. "Create another modifiedProperties and see if it is found."

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wSSp1c here is what I understood. It is working. If you are saying that it won't work for "list.contains(anotherlist)", then yes, I know it won't for that. That's why if you see my answer and the question you will know it is according to the given code and not intended for list in list comparison. If it is still wrong, make a fiddle and let me know.

Comment: Try "Create another modifiedProperty and see if it is found."

Comment: @Paparazzi Thanks for your answer, Could you explain why this is happening?

Comment: Yes I could explain.  Pretty basic stuff you should know if you are a developer.

Comment: @Paparazzi I would like to know, TY. I thought that might be because it's a new prop and reinit so it will have a new hashcode or something but that's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

First Put items to a temp list. then use this code to make them distinct and put them to primary list you want to use:

```
List<string> temp = new List<string> {};
//ADD ITEMS TO temp LIST ANYWAY
List<string> primary;
primary = temp.Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest instead of putting so many **If's** to check duplication..

```
Let them add
```

let them add to the list modifiedProperties

and in the end ..get all **Distinct** values to a new list

```
var new_list  = modifiedProperties.Select(x => x.PropertyName ).Distinct();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if(!modifiedProperties.Contains(modifiedProperty))
   modifiedProperties.Add(modifiedProperty);
```

or

```
if (!modifiedProperties.Exists(x => x.PropertyName == "PropertyName") 
   modifiedProperties.Add(modifiedProperty);
```

You can do it like this.

Check the Item Exists in the List, if false then add it.

You Can also Use `.Exist`  as well.

Check MSDN for **[Exist](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfed8bca(v=vs.110).aspx)** and for **[Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx)**

Comment: how does it deal with the setting of the value in case item is in collection?

Comment: That can be done inside the codition itself right? @GiladGreen